# Does Heroku support chunked HTTP POST data?

Tags: http, post, heroku, chunked

I have an application that I am developing and I would like to send undefined amounts of data to the server using a chunked HTTP/1.1 POST request.

All I can see for now is that nothing seems to be sent to the server after the initial headers:

```
% cat ~/file.mp3 | curl -T - -X POST http://foo.com/source -v
* About to connect() to foo.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying xx.yy.zz.tt...
* Connected to foo.com (xx.yy.zz.tt) port 80 (#0)
> POST /source HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: foo.com
> Accept: */*
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Date: Tue, 14 Jan 2014 14:57:19 GMT
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Length: 13
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host foo.com left intact
Thanks, brah!
```

In the application (node express), if I log the response's "data" event, I see nothing else than:

```
2014-01-14T14:57:19.977995+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/source host=foo.com fwd="xx.yy.zz.tt" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=73ms status=200 bytes=13
```

However, locally, the same logging gives:

```
...
[request] Got 360 bytes of data
[request] Got 16372 bytes of data
[request] Got 16372 bytes of data
[request] Got 16372 bytes of data
[request] Got 48 bytes of data
[request] Got 15974 bytes of data
[request] Got 398 bytes of data
...
```

Is there anything that I could be missing?